# Извлечь данные из массива

Tags: java

Есть стринговский массив. Пользователь угадал слово из массива. Как теперь это слово извлечь из массива, что бы повторно нельзя было угадать?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Под данную задачу больше всего подходит коллекция `HashSet`.

В стандартных коллекциях, реализующих интерфейс `Set` (`HashSet`, `LinkedListSet`, `TreeSet`):

1. Каждый элемент хранится только в одном экземпляре
2. Скорость добавления, удаления и проверки наличия элементов константно, т.е. `O(1)` (кроме `TreeSet`, там `O(log n)`)

   ```
   Set<String> strings = new HashSet<String>();
   strings.add("Вася");
   ....
   strings.add("Асклепиадот");

   String answer = getUserAnswer();

   if(strings.contains(answer)){
       System.out.println("Угадал!");
       strings.remove(answer);
   }
   ```

Comment: Почему вы используете Set здесь?

Comment: @Flippy потому, что он подходит под задачу. Этот тип коллекции хранит уникальные объекты и из него просто эти объекты удалять